# What's the difference between using > and >> in shell?

Tags: unix, shell

I've seen somewhere that we can use >> in shell.
What's the difference between using > and >> in shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`>>` is for appending whereas `>` is for writing (replacing).

Comment: What would be an example of >> ?

Comment: Yeah, be careful when you use > because it will just overwrite the file completely if it already exists whereas >> will either create a new file if none exists or start appending to the end of the existing one.

Comment: @goe: you would use `>>` to keep adding a new line to the end of a file. For example, a log file.

Comment: echo "more text" >> somefile.txt

Comment: +1. Yep, and at the risk of over clarifying, `>` will overwrite (remove) anything that's currently in the file.

Answer (score 5):

If the file exists, `>>` will append to the end of the file, `>` will overwrite it.

Both will create it otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference if the file you're redirecting to already exists:

`>` truncates (i.e. replaces) an existing file.

`>>` appends to the existing file.

Comment: They're different even if the file _doesn't_ exist already (think about `yourprogram >file` and `yourprogram >>file` for my example below -- but this also applies if you use `exec >file`/`exec >>file` within your source, or any other case where a FD is long-lived). Let's say you create a file, and another program writes some data with `>>` while your program is running. If you used `>` then your next write will pick up right after your last write and overwrite that other program's data; if you used `>>` to open the file yourself, then your next write will go _after_ the other program's write.

Answer (score 1):

'>>' will let you append data to a file, where '>' will overwrite it.  For example:

```
# cat test
test file
# echo test > test
# cat test
test
# echo file >> test
# cat test
test
file
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use >, as in:

`$ echo "this is a test" > output.txt`

The > operator will completely overwrite any contents of the file output.txt if it exists. If the file does not exist, it will be created with the contents "this is a test."

This usage:

`$ echo "this is a test" >> output.txt`

Will add the link "this is a test" to any content in output.txt (called 'appending'). If the file does not exist, it will be created, and the text will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more knowledge here.

We can also use `tee` command to perform the same:

```
cat newfile | tee filename - rewrites/replaces the file with new content in filename
cat newfile | tee -a filename - appends to the existing content of the file in filename file
```